# установка одинаковой скорости

Tags: java

у меня есть java код:

```
int vx = enemy_pos_x - t_pos_x;
int vy = enemy_pos_y - t_pos_y;
x += vx;
y += vy;
```

он делает чтобы объект двигался в определённую точку.

```
x,y-позиция объекта
enemy_pos_x,y-позиция точки б
t_pos_x,y-позиция точки а
```

Проблема в том, что шарик летит с разной скоростью и прилетает всегда с одним временем полёта, надо установить одинаковую скорость.

этот код находится в таймере

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Приведите больше кода. Откуда эта скорость берётся собственно. Напишите вопрос достаточно развёрнуто.

Answer (score 1):

Кинематика: `<положение> = <время> * <скорость>`. Вам нужно задать вектор скорости пули `(vx, vy)`. Я буду считать что величина скорости постоянна и хранится в `bullet_speed`.

Направление на врага:

```
dx = enemy_pos_x - t_pos_x;
dy = enemy_pos_y - t_pos_y;
```

Расстояние до врага:

```
dist = (dx ** 2 + dy ** 2) ** 0.5;
```

Скорость по направлению к врагу:

```
vx = bullet_speed * dx / dist;
vy = bullet_speed * dy / dist;
```

Стартовая точка пули:

```
x = t_pos_x
y = t_pos_y
```

В цикле по таймеру находите промежуток времени, умножаете его на скорость, добавляете к координатам пули:

```
dt = now_t - prev_t;
x += vx * dt;
y += vy * dt;
```

Comment: я хотел бы сказать что t_pos_x,y это точка а, то есть башня от которой летит пуля и нам не надо менять позицию башни)))

Comment: короче координаты пули это x,y а t_pos_x,y или bx,y это координаты башни от которой идут пули

Comment: Поправил ещё раз.